# Reference for notions of angular mean

Tags: geometry, statistics, analytic-geometry

Intuitively I'd like to have a "well behaved" mean value M of a series of lines' angular coefficients $m_1$, $m_2$, .., $m_n$ such as for example

$$M=1/n (\sum_{k=1}^n m_k)$$

[image: Image.]

The problem is I'm not sure it is truly well behaved. Converting tangents to arctangents, I'd like to use a function:

**$M: (-\pi/2,\pi/2)^n \to (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$**  (limits not included) such that for all $x, y, z \in$ Domain:

1. $M(x, x)=x$ for every number of equal arguments. In particular $M(x)=x$
2. $M(x, y, z)=M(x,z,y)=M(y,x,z)=M(y,z,x)$, ..., etc for every permutation and number of arguments.
3. $ (x>y) \rightarrow (x>M(x,y)>y)$
4. $M$ isn't in general associative. That is $\lnot M(x,y,z)=M(x,M(y,z))$

Discounting the transformations cartesian cohordinates, radiants, polar, etc what problems might the previous formula for M have? Are there alternatives?
The notion of circular mean doesn't seem helpful as it includes the whole $(0,2\pi)$ and averages over $sin$/$cos$ values which doesn't seem equivalent to what I'm aiming for.
Any reference?
Should I ask MO?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Given the slopes $m_k$ of lines passing through origin, not parallel to the $y$ axis,
$$y = m_k x$$
there are two obvious definitions for their mean or average.

The first one is the mean slope as shown by OP,
$$M = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N} m_k \tag{1}\label{label1}$$
and the second one is the mean angle $\theta$ between each line and the $x$ axis that OP also mentioned (but did not show explicitly),
$$M = \tan{\theta}, \quad \theta = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N} \arctan(m_k) \tag{2}\label{label2}$$
i.e.
$$M = \tan\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N} \arctan(m_k)\right)$$
What is the difference between the two, then?

Consider a set of two lines with $m_1 = 0$ and $m_2 = 4$.

The first one yields $M = 2$, and the second one $M = 0.78$.

The angles of the two original lines are $0^\circ$ and about $76^\circ$.  The angle of the first mean is about $63^\circ$ and the angle of the second mean is about $38^\circ$.

So, the first one yields the mean *slope*, whereas the second one the mean *angle*.  Whichever is more proper for your use case, depends on what the lines and their slopes represent.

In simpler terms, if you consider the lines as the point set where they intersect $x = 1$, mean slope is equivalent to picking the point at $x = 1$ with the mean $y$ coordinate.  For the mean angle, you pick points on say the positive $x$ half of the unit circle, and measure their angles $\varphi$ in radians, along the circle from the intersection with the $x$ axis, with the signed distances being positive on the positive $y$ side, negative on the other side.

Now, let's assume $f$ is a monotonically increasing continuous function over all reals, i.e. $f(x) \lt f(x + \delta)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $0 \lt \delta \in \mathbb{R}$.  Then, $f$ is invertible: $y = f(x) \iff f^{-1}(y) = x$.  With this, we can define an $f$-mean for the lines passing through origin:
$$M_f = f^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N} f(m_k)\right) \tag{3}\label{label3}$$
In the case of $f(x) = x$, this yields $\eqref{label1}$; in the case of $f(x) = \arctan(x)$, $f^{-1}(x) = \tan(x)$, this yields $\eqref{label1}$.

If we consider $\eqref{label1}$ to have a measurement line at $x = 1$, and $\eqref{label2}$ to have a measurement curve a circular arc (half-circle on the positive $x$ axis), then $f$ represents all other possible measurement curves.

Comment: Some of your equations aren't rendering.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: If you mean the $\eqref{label1}$ and $\eqref{label2}$, they're not equations, they're references to equations earlier in the post.  Everything renders fine for me.

Comment: Unfortunately your second notion (2) doesn't quite work (the "mean" of positive angles/tangents may result in a negative one, etc...) and that's the reason why the branch of circular/directional statistics was introduced.
Then I don't (though I'd like to) understand what you mean with "measurement line/ measurement curve" and that final "uniqueness" statement.

Comment: @Zärpä: Sorry, they work fine for me now. Not sure why it wasn't working for me before.

Comment: @Lorenzo: No, the mean of positive angles is always positive.  The mean of any set of angles is always between the minimum and maximum angles in the set.  You may need to try it with some random examples to see.  It is also not circular, but a half-circle, with a discontinuity at perfectly vertical lines (those aligned with $y$ axis).  The measurement curve is a curve along which you measure the deflection of the line.  The mean of a set of lines, using such a curve, is the line that intersects the curve at the mean distance (among the intersections) on that curve.  Would an illustration help?

Comment: In case you generate a random set of lines using random angles $\varphi_k$, remember that $m_k = \tan(\varphi_k)$.  Thus, you do not have a full turn of possible angles, only a half turn.  Perhaps that is what has thrown you off?

Comment: @Zärpä Honestly don't know what threw me off: yeah (2) works as well as an average over angles as long as we don't work $(mod 2\pi)$. And your $M_f$ seems to generalize the problem: interesting but I'm not sure this is what I wanted. Let me digest this a bit.

Comment: @Zärpä Ok. Very nice but I don't get your last sentence: "$f$ represents all possible measurement curves". Doesn't any curve (there are infinite ones) on which we can biijectively project ($f^-1$) a vertical line through the point x=1 naturally translates into a metric over which we can define a notion of "mean"?
Have you got any reference for this "general mean" notion or it was just your intuition? Or you didn't even meant that... Ty